# Migrating Windows task scheduler applications to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have a console application connecting to database and executing DML transactions. This console application is currently scheduled using windows task scheduler. I am planning to migrate this to Azure.

Which is the recommended strategy ?

Should this be moved as Azure webjobs or function apps ?

Comment: What all does the console application do apart from executing DML transactions?

Comment: Just move the data in one db to another using DML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a console project, then it's more easier to use `Azure Webjobs` to achieve that.

To create a webjob, just create a .zip file which includes the .exe / .dll and other necessary files, then upload to azure. For schedule, please refer to [Create a scheduled WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON). For more details, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles).

Note: there're some limitation of azure webjobs / azure function, see [Azure-Web-App-sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#app-service-plans-and-sandbox-limits). But if you only need to connecting to database and executing DML transactions, you can ignore the limits.

And yes, you can also do this via azure function, but since you already have a console project, it's easier to use webjobs.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @Ivan Yang, 
I'm on the same path, in short, I have a console application that has interaction with database, it was designed to be a windows task scheduler job, but I was directed to migrate to Azure.
Searching for right solution online, I found the comment mentioned above, and thought to take the Azure webjob route (with in existing Azure api app service).
I brought api and console projects under one solution.
I was trying to deploy both from Azure DevOps pipelines (continuous integration), but couldn't figure it out.